# IIS 7.0 - IIS adding "private" to cache-control, where is that coming from

Tags: iis-7, web-config, http-headers, browser-cache

Because we protect .PDF files from anonymous users, we have a custom handler so we have an entry

We also made a change to the http headers to add "cache-control: no-cache,no-store" via IIS 7 management which creates web.config entries under system.webserver element as follows:

```
<httpProtocol>

  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="cache-control" value="no-cache,no-store" />
  </customHeaders>

</httpProtocol>
```

When I review the Response headers in a burpsuite session, I see for .aspx pages: cache-control: no-store,no-cache,no-store

But for PDF pages:

Cache-Control: **private**,no-cache,no-store

My goal would be to get everything to just "no-cache, no-store".  I am not sure what I am missing.  There are no other cache settings in the web.config.   Please advise on how to remove "private" from PDF pages and extra no-store from all else.  Other static pages that go through the  System.Web.StaticFileHandler, and they also have the "no-store,no-cache,no-store".

Comment: Ha, I was just getting ready to ask a similar question. I've built my own pass-through proxy.ashx class that implements IHttpHandler. I only want my proxy to pass through headers that originate from the actual server where our RESTful API is hosted. Using Fiddler, I'm noticing the same thing. IIS7 is adding a "private" cache control member somewhere in the pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

Although this post is now a few years old, I thought I would share my solution that may save someone hours of head-scratching.

I have an MVC 4 site setup using IIS, and my aim was to have IIS add headers to certain files (defined by location), by using the `<customHeaders>` section. The 'cache-control' values I had in the `<customHeaders>` section were being appended to the end of 'cache-control: private', magically being added by IIS.

This was because of the **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests** setting in my web.config being set to true

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

This setting was causing one of the IIS Modules (I don't know which) to append the 'cache-control' header to every file being requested from IIS.

So the solution is to set this to false, and manage each of your modules seperatley using the `preCondition` attribute on each.

The **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests** setting was required by earlier versions of MVC because extensionless routing would not work without it. This has since been fixed, more details here

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx

Useful reading on the use of **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests**

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Oct/25/Caveats-with-the-runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests-in-IIS-78

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why IIS 7 is adding "private" to the cache control, but I can show you how I'm getting rid of it in my own ASHX-based pass-through proxy (see 1st comment below Original Post).

```
public class proxy : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        // Remove the 'private' string value from the response.CacheControl member
        if (response.CacheControl == "private")
        {
            response.CacheControl = String.Empty;
        }

        // Do other stuff
    }
}
```

This won't work if you're using the built-in Cassini web development server in Visual Studio. To mess with headers, you need to switch to a full-blown IIS Web Server in your development environment.